Import Beans from custom library to springbootAplication from a different project
I have been struggling trying to create a library with the use of the beans from it to a different  project and call a method from  it
Stack is: Springboot 2.3.4 and Java 1.8 with Maven
The projects are:

Project A : the main project
Project B: custom library that will have 1 method to be invoked

This is the structure of Project B:

CoffeOrderService class:
package com.codecademy.coffeeorders.service;
@Service("coffeOrdersService")
public class CoffeeOrdersService {

@Autowired
@Qualifier("CoffeOrderRepository")
public CoffeeOrderRepository coffeeOrderRepository;

public  CoffeeOrdersService() {
}


public boolean checkRequest(String action){
    /*
    --Stuff doesnt matter
     */
    return true;
}
}

Repository:
package com.codecademy.coffeeorders.repository;
public interface CoffeeOrderRepository extends JpaRepository<CoffeeOrder, Long> {
}

CoffeOrdersAplication
@SpringBootApplication
public class CoffeeOrdersApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(CoffeeOrdersApplication.class, args);
}}

For the SpringbootAplication of project b i have been trying to define ComponentScan to fetch the repository but didnt work for me.
When i add project B as a library with maven to the project A and try to launch it (using Apache Tomcat) i get error like: no such bean definition exception with the Reposiror CoffeOrderRepository that is an attribute to CoffeeOrdersService.
I even tried to define the Bean CoffeOrderService manually inside the Project B springbootAplication context with @Bean notacion  but always get the error for the Repository dependency of project B.
In case you need more info about the projects let me know.
Thanks in advance

Remove the @Qualifier it is wrongly spelled and not needed. Next Project B is a Spring Boot application which you cannot use as a dependency due to the different structure (which is explained here in the documentation).

I removed the @Qualifier and also the SpringBootaplication notation but still getting the error on the project A. When i launch the project if i dont  make any reference to project B i got no error (even if its imported) but when launching invoking the Service i got the same error NoSuchBean exist, and if i add the Bean on SpringBootConfiguration of project A  i got the error that the repository is not defined.

Please read my comment and follow the link I put in there.

First add the Project B as dependency in maven of main Project then in your Project A(Main project) try adding below componentScan in the Main class:
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.codecademy.coffeeorders.*"})

